# Sorting array based on player position

Tags: php, sorting

I have a singular situation where I am trying to sort football players based on their positions.

Let's say I have 10 players and I need to sort them based on their positions:

```
John | Position 1
Bill | Position 1
Gael | Position 2
Phil | Position 2
Joao | Position 2
Cale | Position 3
Bruu | Position 4
Aron | Position 5
Jimm | Position 5
Carl | Position 5
```

I need to try to sort them as equal as possible, in this case:

Team 1 - John, Gael, Cale, Jimm, Carl

Team 2 - Bill, Phil, Joao, Bruu, Aron

I started trying dividing the positions and then sort them in one or another team, but it didn't work as expected because sometimes I have only one player on a position and 3 on the other position.

Comment: Isn't it acceptable to simply make the teams based on alternating odd/even elements of that list ignoring the position?

Comment: I would call this a grouping problem rather than a sorting problem, but I suppose that may just be a regional semantic difference. Also, I don't know if the problem is sufficiently well defined for a good answer. If you're needing to divide the players into teams, what is the criteria for a complete team, and what determines the degree of equality of the teams?

Comment: Are you trying to sort by position, or are you trying to build teams that have, as much as possible, the same number of players in each position?

Comment: @JimMischel That`s it. I am trying to build teams that have, as much as possible, the same number of players in each position.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sorry for being confuse... but as I said.. I am trying to build teams that have, as much as possible, the same number of players in each position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the only reasonable way to do it if you don't have enough players in each position is to sort the players by position, and then go through the list, assigning the next player to the next team. That is, given your list and two teams, you'd write code that does this:

```
John | Position 1 | Team 1
Bill | Position 1 | Team 2
Gael | Position 2 | Team 1
Phil | Position 2 | Team 2
Joao | Position 2 | Team 1
Cale | Position 3 | Team 2
Bruu | Position 4 | Team 1
Aron | Position 5 | Team 2
Jimm | Position 5 | Team 1
Carl | Position 5 | Team 2
```

The code is pretty simple:

```
int numTeams = 2
int team = 0
for each player
{
    Assign player to teams[team]
    team = team + 1
    if (team == numTeams) then
    {
        team = 0
    }
}
```

If you have other restrictions, like a team ideally has x number of position y, then the algorithm would change somewhat to accommodate those restrictions. But you'd have to give me more information before I could supply a suggestion.

Comment: Ideally I would have this restrictions.. but even if I would say that ideally i should have 2 players of position 2 on each team, I don't have four players available.. I think that will do.. I didn't think it would be so simple.. anyway thanks very much